# Swift - TableView How To Create Expandable Section

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, autolayout

I want to create a expandable section with swift. For example in the picture below, Microsoft Outlook IOS application has a expandable section.

[image]

When you click to the section , it seems like below.

[image]

Is this section needs extra code or xcode already has a feature for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a delegate for the custom section you have created, assign it to the `ViewController` and in the delegate method call this when the user taps on it.

```
insertRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

and when the user taps again on the section check if the section is open, if yes then call this method.

```
deleteRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

And don't forget to call `tableView.reloadData()` after these methods.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used the same in one of my project but it was in objective-c, i know one something which will help you. Please have a look,

[Swift Expandable Section](https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section)

I hoe it will helps you.

Thanks.